# Why is my file not found or opened?

Tags: c#, winforms, file-io, nullreferenceexception

I added a .txt file to the \bin\Debug folder, and am trying to open it and read from it like so:

```
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("Credentials.txt")) {
    string line = null;
    do {
        line = reader.ReadLine();
        if (line.Contains("host=")) {
    . . .
```

But, although the file is there, when I get to the "ReadLine()" line, it stops dead in its tracks with:

*System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

### UPDATE

I had to change it from "`do...while (line != null);`" to "`while (! reader.EndOfStream)`"

Comment: @RePRO: What does that solve?

Comment: Where is the file? Have you tried setting the full path in the `OpenText()` command to see if it works? While running check to see which is the current folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That doesn't make sense. I'm not aware of any scenario in which `File.OpenText` returns successfully and the return value is `null`. If `File.OpenText` can not find the file, it throws a `FileNotFoundException`.

Are you sure that the line you state is actually the line throwing the exception? Please check the stack trace carefully.

Note that your loop is in the wrong order. You're calling `StreamReader.ReadLine` and then checking if the line contains "host=". But it could be the case that you've reached the end of the stream in which case `line` will be null and you'll throw. One way to rewrite your loop is to say

```
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
    if (line.Contains("host=")) {
    }
}
```

I'm not saying this is the best way (I don't think it is), but it is a common idiom in C#.

If you insist that you're correct, please print the output of

```
Console.WriteLine(reader == null);
```

which you will place immediately before the

```
line = reader.ReadLine();
```

line.

Answer (score 1):

try using the full path to the file:

```
  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("c:\\Users\\fullpath\\file.txt"))
```

Comment: `StreamReader.ReadLine` would return `String.Empty` on such lines. It uses `null` to mark the end of the stream only.

Comment: Yes, it was reading past the end of the stream and blowing up then (after successfully reading all I wanted, it just kept going. I changed it as noted in my addendum above.